# Simpy Error with environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

I have installed Simpy, and I use Python 3.5. I have the same error:

```
>>> env = simpy.Environment()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    env = simpy.Environment()
AttributeError: module 'simpy' has no attribute 'Environment'
```

It lets me import simpy, but when I do `env = simpy.Environment()` it prints this error.

I have tried uninstalling it, reinstalling, using in the terminal, in the Python's IDLE, in other IDLEs...

The whole code is (from the tutorial):

```
>>> def car(env):
...     while True:
...         print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
...         parking_duration = 5
...         yield env.timeout(parking_duration)
...
...         print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
...         trip_duration = 2
...         yield env.timeout(trip_duration)

>>> import simpy
>>> env = simpy.Environment()
```

And then the error pops-up.

**EDIT (solved):**

I had a file named simpy.py in the same folder. I removed it, and now works perfectly. The code now is:

```
>>> def car(env):
...    while True:
...        print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
...        parking_duration = 5
...        yield env.timeout(parking_duration)
...
...        print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
...        trip_duration = 2
...        yield env.timeout(trip_duration)

>>> import simpy
>>> env = simpy.Environment()
>>> env.process(car(env))
>>> env.run(until=15)
```

And the output:

```
Start parking at 0
Start driving at 5
Start parking at 7
Start driving at 12
Start parking at 14
```

Comment: Which OS do you use? Have you taken a look into the site-packages folder if nothing from SimPy remains there after an uninstall?

Comment: Or does one of the dirs in sys.path (e.g., your current working dir) contain a file called simpy.py?  You can also try "print(simpy.__file__)".

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with your solution. I did exactly this silly thing, too. Consider adding your solution as the answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file named simpy.py in the same folder. I removed it, and now works perfectly. The code now is:

```
>>> def car(env):
...    while True:
...        print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
...        parking_duration = 5
...        yield env.timeout(parking_duration)
...
...        print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
...        trip_duration = 2
...        yield env.timeout(trip_duration)

>>> import simpy
>>> env = simpy.Environment()
>>> env.process(car(env))
>>> env.run(until=15)
```

And the output:

```
Start parking at 0
Start driving at 5
Start parking at 7
Start driving at 12
Start parking at 14
```